# Using an IF in a Mysql query

Tags: mysql, conditional-operator

I have two tables with milions of records that I need to join to display results in different languages. I wish to create a view using a query with IF conditions but I'm not able to understand which is the right way.

What I need to do is: if the following select has a NULL for a single row (in other words the row doesn't have a deutsch translation)...

SELECT one, two FROM tableA A LEFT JOIN tableB B ON (A.id=B.id) WHERE language='de' order by xyz

...then take the english version for the same row and so do this select:

SELECT one, two FROM tableA A LEFT JOIN tableB B ON (A.id=B.id) WHERE language='en' order by xyz

Thanks!
Luca

Comment: I don't know MySql specifically, but does it have a @@rowcount feature?

Answer (score 1):

You query is hard to follow because you don't have aliases.  I am assuming that it is structured like this:

```
select a.one. b.two
from tableA a left join
     tableb b
     on a.id = b.id
where b.language = 'de'
order by xyz
```

The following provides logic that should work in MySQL:

```
SELECT a.one, 
       (case when (select COUNT(*) from b where b.id = a.id and b.language = 'de' and b.two is null) = 0
             then bde.two
             else bend.two
        end) as two
FROM tableA A LEFT JOIN
     tableB Bde
     ON (A.id=B.id) and
        bde.language='de' left join
     tableB ben
     on ben.language = 'en'
order by xyz
```

This is assuming that the `NULL` value is stored in the B table.  If it is lost through a join, then it is a bit harder, something like:

```
SELECT a.one, 
       (case when (select COUNT(*) from a a2 join b b2 on a2.id = b2.id and b2.language = 'de' and b2.two is null) = 0
             then bde.two
             else bend.two
        end) as two
FROM tableA A LEFT JOIN
     tableB Bde
     ON (A.id=B.id) and
        bde.language='de' left join
     tableB ben
     on ben.language = 'en'
order by xyz
```

Comment: Thank you really for your help. I changed the query in this way
`SELECT 
g.geonameid, alternateName, latitude, longitude, fclass, fcode, country
FROM geoname g LEFT JOIN alternatename a ON (g.geonameid=a.geonameid) WHERE IF(select COUNT(*) from geoname g JOIN alternatename a ON g.geonameid=a.geonameid and isoLanguage='de', 1, 0)=1 THEN isolanguage='de' ELSE isolanguage='en' order by isPreferredName`

but I receive an error near WHERE if(select...
I tried your query but whitout success.